# mediaplayer R file complications

Tags: java, android

i want to make it work

```
MediaPlayer[] playword = new MediaPlayer[];//Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer ,on eclipse a big X
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
     playword[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier("word" + Integer.toString(i), "raw", getPackageName()));
     playword[i].setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 }
```

but i got an error in the R file

i added a word before the numbers

Comment: 2 should be any numberi just did checks

Comment: 1, why creating two MediaPlayer objects? 2. please post stacktrace or error message from Your IDE

Comment: You haven't updated your code to my example? Remove `R.raw.Integer."word"+toString(i)` and replace with `getResources().getIdentifier("word" + Integer.toString(i), "raw", getPackageName())`

Comment: See my latest answer, you have not initialised the array.

Comment: i did i even edited the post it wont let me run it cause initialization is wrong oh need to add length sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

`MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Integer.toString(i));`

with

`MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier("word" + Integer.toString(i), "raw", getPackageName()));`

This will find the numbered files in the `res/raw` folder e.g. `word1`, `word2` etc.

Also, your `MediaPlayer` array is not initialised, the following should work

```
int NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS = 3; // Number of Sounds
MediaPlayer[] playword = new MediaPlayer[NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS];
 for(int i=0;i < NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS; i++){
     playword[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier("word" + Integer.toString(i), "raw", getPackageName()));
     playword[i].setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 }
```

I am not sure why you are using an Array of `MediaPlayer` objects, but if you feel this is required I would use a `List<MediaPlayer>` instead of a `MediaPlayer[]`.

Comment: yeah thats why im trying to do an array of numbered files such that 0=0 1=1 and so on sec icheck what you gave me hope it work

Comment: @learning Good point, any resource must begin with an alphabetic character. In that case, rename them adding something like `sound_` in front of their current names and I will change my answer accordingly. Also make sure you edit the physical file names, NOT the `R.java` file, you should never need to edit that.

Comment: @learning I updated my example, can you confirm this now works?

Comment: no it gives me an error it says attempt to read from null array

Comment: @learning You are going to have to be more specific, as the code I have provided is a valid solution.

Comment: error:Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer

Comment: @learning See updated answer. If these sounds are short, I would suggest reading the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) documentation

Comment: i saw the answer the intialization dont pass eclipse debugging and i use media for now cause i know nothing on the soudpool and i want to make it work for now

Comment: @learning The code I have provided works fine, please tell me exactly what Eclipse says or create a new question as it seems your problem is not related to the question. If my code has helped, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: all i want is to load a random sound from all the sounds i got in the array but i need to initialize them which with this R thing

Comment: @learning Yes, I realise that. The code I have provided in my comment does that - It should work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Question right, you want to do something like this:

```
MediaPlayer[] playword;
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

    int tmpSoundIdentifier = this.getResources().getIdentifier("sound_" + i, "raw", this.getPackageName());

    playword[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, tmpSoundIdentifier);
    playword[i].setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  }
```

Comment: jsut tried it got an error of identifier i guess i cant use just numbers

Comment: then give it a name: sound_0 , sound_1 and then: ...getIdentifier("sound_"+i,"raw",....)